# A prepared String is not being saved completely when not debugging

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a Program which should save permanently values to a .txt file. When I debug it by putting a breakpoint into the code it works fine. But when letting it work for a while it only saves the last value caught instead of the last 3.

The method `ExecuteStrategy` is being executed every minute.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bot_V1._0
{
   public class SaveAllMinuteBarsStrategy : IStrategy
{
    public Guid StrategyGuid { get; set; }
    //private static string[] Data = new string[8];
    private string DataDax { get; set; }
    private string DataDow { get; set; }
    private string DataOil { get; set; }
    private string DataGold { get; set; }
    private string DataSpy { get; set; }
    private string DataEsd { get; set; }
    private string DataEgp { get; set; }
    private string DataUpy { get; set; }
    private string xPath = @"G:\TradingBot\Saved Candles folder";
    private DateTime firstEnter;
    const char LF = '\n';
    public SaveAllMinuteBarsStrategy (Guid StrategyCGuid)
    {
        this.StrategyGuid = StrategyGuid;
    }
    public List<ShareAndTimeRange> InitStrategy (Guid stratGuid)
    {
        firstEnter = DateTime.Now;
        var Dax = new ShareAndTimeRange("DAX", 1, stratGuid, null, false);
        var Dow = new ShareAndTimeRange("DOW", 1, stratGuid, null, false);
        var Oil = new ShareAndTimeRange("OIL", 1, stratGuid, null, false);
        var Gold = new ShareAndTimeRange("GOLD", 1, stratGuid, null, false);
        var Spy = new ShareAndTimeRange("SPY", 1, stratGuid, null, false);
        var Esd = new ShareAndTimeRange("EUR/USD", 1, stratGuid, null, false);
        var Egb = new ShareAndTimeRange("EUR/GBP", 1, stratGuid, null, false);
        var Ujp = new ShareAndTimeRange("USD/JPY", 1, stratGuid, null, false);
        var ElementList = new List<ShareAndTimeRange>();

        ElementList.Add(Dax);
        ElementList.Add(Dow);
        ElementList.Add(Oil);
        ElementList.Add(Gold);
        ElementList.Add(Spy);
        ElementList.Add(Esd);
        ElementList.Add(Egb);
        ElementList.Add(Ujp);

        return ElementList;
    }
    public void ExecuteStrategy(ShareAndTimeRange Share)
    {            
        SaveDataHourly(Share);       
    }
    private void SaveDataHourly(ShareAndTimeRange Share)
    {
        if (Share.Candle == null)
            return;
        var PreparedString = Share.Candle.Time.ToString("yyyyMMdd HHmmss") + ";";
        PreparedString = PreparedString + Share.Candle.Open + ";" + Share.Candle.High + ";";
        PreparedString = PreparedString + Share.Candle.Low + ";" + Share.Candle.Close;
        PreparedString = PreparedString + LF;
        switch (Share.ShareName)
        {
            case ("DAX"):
                {
                    DataDax = DataDax + PreparedString;
                    //Data[0] = Data[0] + 
                    bool reset = HDMYSaving(Share, DataDax);
                    if (reset)
                        DataDax = "";
                    break;
                }
            case ("DOW"):
                {
                    DataDow = DataDow + PreparedString;
                    bool reset = HDMYSaving(Share, DataDow);
                    if (reset)
                        DataDow = "";
                    break;
                }
            case ("OIL"):
                {
                    DataOil = DataOil + PreparedString;
                    bool reset = HDMYSaving(Share, DataOil);
                    if (reset)
                        DataOil = "";
                    break;
                }
            case ("GOLD"):
                {
                    DataGold = DataGold + PreparedString;
                    bool reset = HDMYSaving(Share, DataGold);
                    if (reset)
                        DataGold = "";
                    break;
                }
            case ("SPY"):
                {
                    DataSpy = DataSpy + PreparedString;
                    bool reset = HDMYSaving(Share, DataSpy);
                    if (reset)
                        DataSpy = "";
                    break;
                }
            case ("EUR/USD"):
                {
                    DataEsd = DataEsd + PreparedString;
                    bool reset = HDMYSaving(Share, DataEsd);
                    if (reset)
                        DataEsd = "";
                    break;
                }
            case ("EUR/GBP"):
                {
                    DataEgp = DataEgp + PreparedString;
                    bool reset = HDMYSaving(Share, DataEgp);
                    if (reset)
                        DataEgp = "";
                    break;
                }
            case ("USD/JPY"):
                {
                    DataUpy = DataUpy + PreparedString;
                    bool reset = HDMYSaving(Share, DataUpy);
                    if (reset)
                        DataUpy = "";
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    private void SavePersistentData (string FolderName , string FileName, string Share )
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(FolderName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderName);
        }
        string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderName, FileName);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Create(fullPath);
            fs.Dispose();
        }
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullPath, false))
        {
            sw.Write(Share);
            sw.Dispose();
        }
        //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullPath, Share);   
    }
    private void SavePersistent (string ReadFolder , string WriteFolder , string WriteFolderFile)
    {
        DirectoryInfo ParDir = new DirectoryInfo(ReadFolder);
        string dat = "";
        foreach (var item in ParDir.GetFiles())
        {
            var elem = System.IO.Path.Combine(ReadFolder, item.Name);
            dat += System.IO.File.ReadAllText(elem);
        }
        SavePersistentData(WriteFolder, WriteFolderFile, dat);
        foreach (var item in ParDir.GetFiles())
        {
            var del = System.IO.Path.Combine(ReadFolder, item.Name);
            File.Delete(del);
        }
    }
    private bool HDMYSaving(ShareAndTimeRange Share, string Values)
    {
        if (Share.Candle == null)
            return false;
        bool toReset = false;
        string SharePath =  System.IO.Path.Combine(xPath, Share.ShareName);//c:\TradingBot\Saved Candles folder\"Sharename"\
        string HourPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(SharePath, "Hour Data");//c:\TradingBot\Saved Candles folder\"Sharename"\Hour Data
        int res;
        int resuzt = Math.DivRem(Share.Candle.Time.Minute,3,out res);
        if ( res == 0) //0 Share.Candle.Time.Minute == 0
        {
            DateTime DateToWriteH = Share.Candle.Time;
            string HourFilePath = DateToWriteH.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + ".txt";
            SavePersistentData(HourPath, HourFilePath, Values);
            toReset = true;
        }
        DateTime DateToWriteD = Share.Candle.Time.AddDays(-1);
        string DayPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(SharePath, "Day Data");//c:\TradingBot\Saved Candles folder\"Sharename"\Day Data
        string DayFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(DayPath, DateToWriteD.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt");
        if (Share.Candle.Time.Hour == 0 && Share.Candle.Time.Minute == 0 && !System.IO.File.Exists(DayFilePath))
        {
            SavePersistent(HourPath, DayPath, DateToWriteD.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt");
        }
        DateTime DateToWriteM = Share.Candle.Time.AddMonths(-1);
        string MonthPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(SharePath, "Month Data");//c:\TradingBot\Saved Candles folder\"Sharename"\Month Data
        string MonthFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(MonthPath, DateToWriteM.ToString("yyyyMM") + ".txt");
        if (Share.Candle.Time.Day == 1 && Share.Candle.Time.Hour == 0 && Share.Candle.Time.Minute == 0 && !System.IO.File.Exists(MonthFilePath))
        {
            SavePersistent(DayPath, MonthPath, DateToWriteM.ToString("yyyyMM") + ".txt");
        }
        DateTime DateToWriteY = Share.Candle.Time.AddYears(-1);
        string YearPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(SharePath, "Year Data");//c:\TradingBot\Saved Candles folder\"Sharename"\Year Data
        string YearFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(YearPath, DateToWriteY.ToString("yyyy") + ".txt");
        if (Share.Candle.Time.Month == 1 && Share.Candle.Time.Day == 1 && Share.Candle.Time.Hour == 0 && Share.Candle.Time.Minute == 0 && !System.IO.File.Exists(YearFilePath))
        {
            SavePersistent(MonthPath, YearPath, DateToWriteY.ToString("yyyy") + ".txt");
        }
        return toReset;
    }

}
```

Is there a problem having a lot of Events which are fired every 2 seconds or every minute?
Thanks!!

Comment: do not just dump your entire program into your question. actually show the part you are having a problem with.

Comment: @user1666620: Ideally, still posting a complete example... just a minimal one.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right, but 200+ lines of code in a question is a bit much

Comment: @user1666620: Sure, I wasn't saying the OP shouldn't cut it down - but a [mcve] is much more helpful than just a snippet.

Comment: The problem is when debugging it, the Code works fine, but by executing it loses parts of the string.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem. It was on another Class. The Fault was firing an event every time the program colleted a new value, but the program schould wait for the other "WebsTakenInCare".
Here is the Code before:

```
            if (DataList.Count() == WebsTakenInCare)
            {
               FinalizedData = ShortenUpData(DataList);
               DataList.Clear();                
            }
            BuildCandles(FinalizedData);
```

and after changing:

```
            if (DataList.Count() == WebsTakenInCare)
        {
            FinalizedData = ShortenUpData(DataList);
            DataList.Clear();
            BuildCandles(FinalizedData);
        }
        else
            return;
```

regards!